# How to stop scrolling when popup opens

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, overflow

Currently, when you click 'more info' and the popup opens. You are able to scroll and you'll see that the background moves. I want to prevent the ability for scrolling while the popup is opening, what would I do to take care of this issue? I tried playing with `overflow:hidden;` in CSS but it didn't work for this. I will add a link to my fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/ctose0Lq/11/

```js
/*=============== SERVICES MODAL ===============*/
const modalViews = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal'),
  modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.services__button'),
  modalClose = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal-close')

let modal = function(modalClick) {
  modalViews[modalClick].classList.add('active-modal')
}

modalBtns.forEach((mb, i) => {
  mb.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal(i)
  })
})

modalClose.forEach((mc) => {
  mc.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalViews.forEach((mv) => {
      mv.classList.remove('active-modal')
    })
  })
})


/*=============== Products MODAL ===============*/
const modalViews2 = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal'),
  modalBtns2 = document.querySelectorAll('.products__button'),
  modalClose2 = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal-close')

let modal2 = function(modalClick) {
  modalViews[modalClick].classList.add('active-modal')
}

modalBtns2.forEach((mb, i) => {
  mb.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal2(i)
  })
})

modalClose2.forEach((mc) => {
  mc.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalViews2.forEach((mv) => {
      mv.classList.remove('active-modal')
    })
  })
})
```

```css
/*=============== SERVICES ===============*/

.section__services {
  padding: 4.5rem 0 1rem;
}

.section__title,
.section__subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: 1.55rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.section__subtitle {
  display: block;
  font-size: .813rem;
  color: black;
}

.container__services {
  max-width: 968px;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.grid__services {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.25rem;
}

.services__container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.services__card {
  padding: 5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #bdbcbfba, #4769b878), url(../img/blueflower-removebg-preview.webp) no-repeat top center;
}

.services__card2 {
  padding: 5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #bdbcbfba, #c4bc4893), url(../img/yellowflower-removebg-preview.webp) no-repeat top center;
}

.services__card3 {
  padding: 5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #bdbcbfba, #b38dd194), url(../img/pinkflower-removebg-preview.webp) no-repeat top center;
}

.services__card4 {
  padding: 5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #bdbcbfba, #de6d3498), url(../img/salmonflower-removebg-preview.webp) no-repeat top center;
}

.section__services .services__container .services__card,
.section__services .services__container .services__card2,
.section__services .services__container .services__card3,
.section__services .services__container .services__card4 {
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(43, 31, 31, 0.228);
  border: .5px solid #9cd1f5;
}

.services__title {
  font-size: 1.35rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-align: center;
}

.services__button {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: .9rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 55%;
}

.services__button:hover .services__icon {
  transform: translateX(.25rem);
}

.services__icon {
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: .4s;
}

.services__modal {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: hsla(219, 28%, 16%, 0.7);
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .4s;
  z-index: 15;
}

.services__modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #daeef6;
  padding: 4.5rem 1.5rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 15;
}

.services__modal-title,
.services__modal-description {
  text-align: center;
}

.services__modal-title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.services__modal-description {
  font-size: .813rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.services__modal-list {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: .75rem;
}

.services__modal-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.services__modal-icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
  cursor: default;
}

.services__modal-icon-x {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: red;
  cursor: default;
}

.services__modal-info {
  font-size: .913rem;
}

.services__modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--title-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal__Z-index {
  z-index: 1000 !important;
}


/*Active modal*/

.active-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .services__button {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: .9rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: .25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 35%;
  }
}


/* For small devices */

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .services__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 250px);
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 445px) {
  .section__title {
    font-size: 1.35rem;
  }
  .services__modal-info {
    font-size: .7rem;
  }
  .services__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 250px);
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .section__services {
    padding: 6.5rem 0 1rem;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  .services__button {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: .9rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: .25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 55%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .specialty_button_center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .container__partners {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .services__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 200px);
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .container__partners {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
  .services__modal-content {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 4.5rem 2.5rem 2.5rem;
    z-index: 15;
  }
  .services__modal-description {
    padding: 0 3.5rem;
  }
  .specialty__category {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 200px);
    column-gap: 3rem;
  }
  .blog__content {
    grid-template-columns: 450px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .machine__content {
    grid-template-columns: 450px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .contact__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
  }
  .contact__form {
    width: 380px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .services__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 200px);
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .services__modal-content {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 4.5rem 2.5rem 2.5rem;
    z-index: 15;
  }
  .services__modal-description {
    padding: 0 3.5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .section__services {
    padding: 6.5rem 0 1rem;
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
  .services__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 272px);
    column-gap: 3rem;
  }
  .container__services {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .services__card {
    padding: 5rem 2rem 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .services__car2 {
    padding: 5rem 2rem 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .services__card3 {
    padding: 5rem 2rem 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .services__card4 {
    padding: 5rem 2rem 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!--=============== REMIXICONS ===============-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--=============== BOXICONS ===============-->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

  <!--=============== CSS ===============-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">





</head>

<body>



  <!--=============== SERVICES ===============-->


  <section id="whatweprovide" class="services section__services">


    <span class="section__subtitle">Our Info Cards</span>
    <h2 class="section__title">What We Provide</h2>

    <div class="services__container container__services grid__services">
      <div class="services__card">
        <h3 class="services__title">Test 4</h3>

        <span class="services__button">
                More Info <i class='bx bx-right-arrow-alt services__icon'></i>
            </span>
      </div>




      <div class="services__card2">
        <h3 class="services__title">Test 3</h3>

        <span class="services__button">
                More Info <i class='bx bx-right-arrow-alt services__icon'></i>
            </span>
      </div>





      <div class="services__card3">
        <h3 class="services__title">Test 2</h3>

        <span class="services__button">
                More Info <i class='bx bx-right-arrow-alt services__icon'></i>
            </span>
      </div>




      <div class="services__card4">
        <h3 class="services__title">Test 1</h3>

        <span class="services__button">
                More Info <i class='bx bx-right-arrow-alt services__icon'></i>
            </span>
      </div>



    </div>
  </section>



  <!--=============== Service Cards ===============-->
  <div class="services__modal modal__Z-index">
    <div class="services__modal-content">
      <i class='bx bx-x services__modal-close'></i>

      <h3 class="services__modal-title">Coming Soon </h3>
      <p class="services__modal-description">
        Test Textr skjhte e
      </p>

      <ul class="services__modal-list">
        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>






  <div class="services__modal .modal__Z-index">
    <div class="services__modal-content">
      <i class='bx bx-x services__modal-close'></i>

      <h3 class="services__modal-title">Coming Soon </h3>
      <p class="services__modal-description">
        Test Textr skjhte e
      </p>

      <ul class="services__modal-list">
        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="services__modal modal__Z-index">
    <div class="services__modal-content">
      <i class='bx bx-x services__modal-close'></i>

      <h3 class="services__modal-title">Coming Soon</h3>
      <p class="services__modal-description">
        Test Textr skjhte e
      </p>

      <ul class="services__modal-list">
        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>





  <div class="services__modal modal__Z-index">
    <div class="services__modal-content">
      <i class='bx bx-x services__modal-close'></i>

      <h3 class="services__modal-title">Coming Soon...</h3>
      <p class="services__modal-description">
        Test Textr skjhte e
      </p>

      <ul class="services__modal-list">
        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

        <li class="services__modal-item">
          <i class='bx bx-check services__modal-icon'></i>
          <p class="services__modal-info">
            Test Textr skjhte e
          </p>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!--=============== Service Cards End ===============-->
  <!--=============== End of SERVICES ===============-->








  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>




  </main>



  <!--=============== GSAP ===============-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>


  <!--=============== MAIN JS ===============-->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'` on the click event (inside `addEventListener('click', () => {...})`).

Try the following JavaScript code:

```
/*=============== SERVICES MODAL ===============*/
const modalViews = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal'),
  modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.services__button'),
  modalClose = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal-close')

let modal = function (modalClick) {
  modalViews[modalClick].classList.add('active-modal')
}

modalBtns.forEach((mb, i) => {
  mb.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal(i)
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  })
})

modalClose.forEach((mc) => {
  mc.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
    modalViews.forEach((mv) => {
      mv.classList.remove('active-modal')
    })
  })
})


/*=============== Products MODAL ===============*/
const modalViews2 = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal'),
  modalBtns2 = document.querySelectorAll('.products__button'),
  modalClose2 = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal-close')

let modal2 = function (modalClick) {
  modalViews[modalClick].classList.add('active-modal')
}

modalBtns2.forEach((mb, i) => {
  mb.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal2(i)
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  })
})

modalClose2.forEach((mc) => {
  mc.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
    modalViews2.forEach((mv) => {
      mv.classList.remove('active-modal')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: @franco-a-torres That does solve the issue and prevents scrolling while the popup is open however once you close out the popup you are no longer able to scroll on the website.